# When I try to set up MySQL in Netbeans, "Register MySQL Server" is greyed out

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm following the instructions [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) which say:

> Register your MySQL server in the IDE, if the server is not
> registered. To register a MySQL server, go to the IDE's Services
> window, right-click the Databases node, and select Register MySQL
> server.

However, when I follow the instructions I find that the option `Register MySQL Server` is greyed out. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I already had a MySQL server configured (not sure how but I must have done it earlier). I deleted it and now I can register a new one.

This was thanks to the answer I found [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191967), from Jiri Rechtacek:

> The action "Register MySQL Server" can be enabled if and only if no
>   MySQL server is registered already. I guess you have "MySQL Server"
>   node under Databases root. If I'm wrong reopen with more detail, or
>   sceenshot showing this issue. Thanks